# F# Problem Loading Assemblies: "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to F# and Visual Studio and I'm running into wall trying to figure out what the issue is here.  I'm trying to use SqlDataProvider.  My code:

```
module HelloSquare


open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql

let square x = x * x

type PortalProd = SqlDataProvider<
                Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MYSQL,
                "Server=localhost;Database=test;User=test;Password=test;",
                UseOptionTypes=true>

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let test = 12312
    printfn "%d squared is: %d!" 12 (square 12)
    0 // Return an integer exit code
```

The error I get is:

`Error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Protobuf, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=APublicKey'.`

I added protobuf using nuget but the error persists.

[image]

Hopefully this is something simple but I could use some help.

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.0.1 (build 1)

Comment: try Dapper, its stable, works and fast, i've been bashing my head on the highly touted typeproviders and they have come up short. I use Dapper.